Unity mirror discovery Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'UnityAction<ServerResponse>'
I am working on a multiplayer game with unity mirror, I am making connections successfully with networkdiscoveryhud, but when I try to create my own menu buttons instead of networkdiscoveryhud, and I add addlistener and try to find the servers on the network with discovery, Im getting the this error.

networkDiscovery.OnServerFound.AddListener(OnServerFound);

error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'UnityAction<ServerResponse>'


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Mirror;
using Mirror.Discovery;

    private NetworkDiscovery networkDiscovery;
    List<ServerResponse> foundServers;
    private bool serverFound;

    void Start()
    {
        networkDiscovery = NetworkManager.singleton.GetComponent<NetworkDiscovery>();
        foundServers = new List<ServerResponse>();
        networkDiscovery.OnServerFound.AddListener(OnServerFound);
    }
    public void OnServerFound(ServerResponse server)
    {
        Debug.Log("Server is found");
        if (server.EndPoint != null)
        {
            serverFound = true;
            foundServers.Add(server);
        }
    }


I have solved the problem
I changed OnServerFound function name to OnDiscoveredServer and replace the param AddListener metot to
networkDiscovery.OnServerFound.AddListener(OnDiscoveredServer);

it is working now.
